# Get pixel colour from picturebox with drawn graphics in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, graphics

I have created some graphics in a pictureBox using createGraphics, the graphics are very simple blocks either one set colour or they're blank. Next I want to read detect with a mouse click if the cursor position is coloured or not.

I thought this would be simple but can't get anything to work. There are examples for doing this using a bitmap and GetPixel but that doesn't work with drawn graphics.

My code is for editing fonts that are printed to small LCD screens using microcontrollers and stored in font files. Here is some code that is not working this gets the block of the pixel of the character but I also need to know if the area clicked was white or red.

```
Private Sub VP_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles pictureBox0.MouseClick
        Dim grid As Integer = 10
        Dim LocX As Integer = e.X
        Dim locY As Integer = e.Y
        TextBoxX.Text = e.X
        TextBoxY.Text = e.Y
        TextBoxX.ForeColor = Color.IndianRed
        TextBoxY.ForeColor = Color.IndianRed

        Dim lX As Integer = e.X \ grid
        Dim lY As Integer = e.Y \ grid
        Dim uX As Integer = lX + 1
        Dim uY As Integer = lY + 1

        TextBox21.Text = "(" & lX & "," & lY & ")  (" & uX & "," & uY & ")"

        Dim c As Color
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = pictureBox0.Image.Clone
        c = bmp.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y)

        TextBox22.Text = c.ToString

    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What do you get if you use GetPixel?  can you add the code into the question please.

Comment: CreateGraphics sounds like VB.NET not VB6? - If your drawing simple blocks you could maintain a list of coordinate rectangles and check for intersections with the click coords.

Comment: I have added some more information and code I have tried. In visual studio properties it says Target framework: .NET Framework 4.6.1